# What ports should be closed in windows 10?

Tags: network, ports, windows-10

How can I close ports in windows 10 and what ports are unnecessary to be open? How do I find these open ports to close?

Also if I close a specific port on windows 10 do I have to close the outbound and inbound port?

Comment: It's the services on the ports that matter. What ports do you *need* to be open? There aren't "inbound" and "outbound" *ports*. The ports accept traffic inbound or outbound. And again, that depends on what you need. The ***firewall*** is what you need to "close" a port.

Comment: ports are not vulnerable.the application that run on them are(sometimes)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I close ports in windows 10 and what ports are unnecessary to
>   be open?

You can either use embedded windows firewall to do that, or can use the firewall on the router, if it supports acls

> How do I find these open ports to close?

You can use this command:

```
netstat -an
```

Or you can use a port scanning software to find out what services are waiting for incoming connections on your PC.

Or you can investigate the rules on your Firewall to determine them. Understand that firewall turned off means no ports are **filtered**, and no **explicit rule "deny all"**
also means that ports not explicitly closed will not be **filtered**.

> Also if I close a specific port on windows 10 do I have to close the
>   outbound and inbound port?

Inbound ports means that something can be relayed to your PC through that port. Imagine a fence with 65535 pickets. Each number represents a single picket. Open inbound port with number 80 for example, means that the picket number 80 is not present in the fence. On the technical note, port 80 are reserved by ICANN for web servers on http protocol, so having it open on an average user PC means something fishy.

Outbound ports means that your PC will connect to another PC\Server\Application on PC\Server\Whatever via that port. It will not connect by creating a packet from port 80 to create to port 80 on a target, but rather send the packets to the open port 80 on the target.

Originating packets use dynamic ports to connect to outbound ports. But that is too deep already.

Comment: So for an example, if I specify a firewall rule can I close that port? Also do I have to specify a rule for both inbound and outbound or can I do just one rule to close the port? I am having trouble figuring out how to do this. What are ports that should remain open for outbound? Should all outbound ports be closed if I have no need of connecting to my pc from the outside? Should I flat out close port 80?

Comment: Turning Microsoft Firewall with default settings should be ok. If any application on your PC will attempt make internet connection, firewall will pop notification.